Is there a way to execute CLI command in IntelliJ in Before launch (Run/Debug configurations)
Before running anything (e.g. a TestNG test), I want to execute a CLI command, and I would like to place it into the Run/Debug window Before launch section if it is possible.
So far, I have found a way to create a bash script, there I can write the command. Here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-531/Command-Line-Run-Configuration
However I cannot find a way to execute it before launch.

According to the documentation on Run Configurations - Before Launch: "In this area, you can specify tasks to be performed before starting the selected run/debug configuration. The tasks are performed in the order they appear in the list."
As I've never done this, I'm not sure which of the options you would need for your script.
